# How should I compare the hashes in my baseline.txt file with the hashes of the files in a directory?

Tags: python, integrity

I am designing a file integrity monitor in Python. I was able to create a function that iterates through all files in a given directory, hashes the contents of each one, and stores the hashes in a baseline.txt file next to the file's path. Now I'm trying to figure out how to compare the hashes within baseline.txt to the current hashes of the files. This is what I have right now.

```
def comp_baseline():
    # Begin (continuously) monitoring files with saved baseline
    filehash = hashlib.sha512() # Create a file hashing object
    base_dict = {}
    if os.path.exists("baseline.txt"): # Load file|hash from baseline.txt and store them in a dictionary
        f = open("baseline.txt", 'r')
        for line in f:
            key, value = line.strip().split(' | ')
            base_dict[key] = value
        print(base_dict) # Dictionary created. Keys = files in given directory. Values = hashes of those files

        # Compare current file: hash to dictionary to check if it's in there
        # if not, it means the file does not exist
        # if the file exists but the hash is different, the file has been compromised

        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            for filename in os.listdir(directory):
                fn = os.path.join(directory, filename)
                with open(fn, 'rb') as f2:
                    while True:
                        data = f2.read(BUF_SIZE)
                        filehash.update(data)
                        if fn in base_dict[key]:
                            print("File found")        
                    
    else:
        print("Baseline file does not exist in local directory.")
```

Edit: I forgot to clarify, that I want to transfer the filepaths and hashes into a dictionary so that I may directly compare the hash to dictionary values, which are the hashes. Just wondering how I can compare the hash to the value that belongs to the matching filepath.
This is what baseline.txt looks like

```
/home/kali/Documents/test_files/b.txt | c49b73859752f36533fe7efe8994a697f88b1f9fac06003ca2e7d5d1d97ddb230bebe54fc36610d105625862998126ff5974b40c322d719fd706c1db8d503958
/home/kali/Documents/test_files/e.txt | 2d32d7704de22f9016fc75269ee54a4576864e9983aeb187fe06bf00113e5a01b5c93b8123a1e20bcc1c213afe09ed70e7bf0e4b49df80a046b8f91a7daa0b17
/home/kali/Documents/test_files/a.txt | a07b2986313eff8ebe7d73d4f2432bd9c2a7d7c43867cfcb0712f30868302921c5b09d73cd823c6d15aaa6e66ecd024b11d1f09bdf95178031cfd539621b24b0
/home/kali/Documents/test_files/d.txt | febdef5ebb1eec24417b9341f42f3259f4e5918ebb6993fbd362574a8305b03b46da5046b14e7761ede08cb9c4176e89752d525c2917bf701e139397bc561040
/home/kali/Documents/test_files/c.txt | bc7f9d6af7a95e4ca293bc96e19f8047faa7ceefc516043fc16c29ee673855bda84c84dc57cb0f285301dd21f3fbada2a47548f2fbc03187d95c78eb4612822c
```

It should compare each hash in the txt file to each file in the directory and if one doesn't match then it should give an alert

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Read each hash value from the text file, calculate the actual current hash of the corresponding file, and compare them.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm sorry, I did not clarify. I suppose what I'm asking is how I can compare the hash of the file that is CURRENTLY being iterated through, to the dictionary hash value of the matching filepath key. Should I utilize a while loop?

Comment: A `for` loop on each line of the baseline text file seems like a natural way to do it.

Comment: Typically you use a `for` loop when you know exactly how many times you want the loop to run (in this case, one loop for each line in the baseline text file), and you  use a `while` loop when the end condition is unpredictable (i.e. maybe you're asking the user for input over and over, and they might enter one, two, or a hundred inputs.)

Answer (score 0):

My aproach to checking the files would be to itterate over every line in the 'baseline.txt' file. Then split at the " | " read the file on the left and genorate a hash, then compare it to the right value.

```py
# read baseline
with open("baseline.txt", "r") as f:
    # look over every file and recorded hash
    for line in f.readlines():
        fp, hash = line.split(" | ")
        # fp = file path

        with open(fp, 'rb') as tf:
            test_hash = hashlib.sha256(tf.read())
            if test_hash != hash:
                print(f"{fp!r} has a non matching hash")
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the suggestion! I tried your method, but because I am trying to iterate through the given directory, the test_hash loop doesn't work because the files it's going through don't match the order of files within the directory. 
"Please enter 'A' or 'B': b
/home/kali/Documents/test_files/b.txt' has a non-matching hash.
/home/kali/Documents/test_files/e.txt' has a non-matching hash.
/home/kali/Documents/test_files/a.txt' has a non-matching hash.
/home/kali/Documents/test_files/d.txt' has a non-matching hash.
/home/kali/Documents/test_files/c.txt' has a non-matching hash."

Comment: This code is supposed to be independant of the dictionary and the order should not matter. This code requires no dictionary, instead it opens the files specified by baseline and chesk them, no dict is required. Could you make sure that the way these hashes are genorated isn't messing you up.